# how to install IE6 on our computer without modifying the registry?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, internet, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

What's the easiest way to install IE6 on our computer?

Whenever I try to install it.. they reject it because "a newer version of IE has already been installed"

I googled around and there are some solutions that tells me to edit the registry settings..

So basically before I even go down that route, I was wondering is there an easy way to install IE6 in our computer?

I was thinking perhaps there is a zipped copy of IE6 that I could simply unzip and use?

(32-bit Windows Vista Version 6.0 Home Premium SP 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft offers free virtual systems with different versions of IE pre-installed - including one with WinXP and IE6.

The only change needed on your PC is installing the VirtualPC software and afterwards you can test your web-application with any IE version you want. Just download the correspondent VPC image from Microsoft:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11575

Answer (score 2):

I have used [MultipleIEs](http://multipleies.en.softonic.com/) for this. It installs IE 3, 4, 5, and 6 (you can choose which version(s) you want at install time) along side whatever other version you currently have.

I only wish it would support 7, 8 and 9 simultaneously, too.

Comment: is there an updated version of this app? for some reason it keeps crashing when i try to run it: **The application failed to intialize properly (0xc0000142). Click OK to terminate the application.**

Answer (score 1):

You can try IETester http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Browsers/IETester.shtml. It bundles several versions of IE, and I'm pretty sure 6 is one of them. It won't mess with any versions already installed.

As a side-node you can also look into http://www.sandboxie.com/ which may allow you install IE6 and revert any changes to the registry safely.

Comment: i've looked at it.. but i don't understand how is it related.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.